# Get path of nw archive in node webkit application

Tags: node-webkit

I am building multiple applications with nwjs(node webkit).
My applications will use the same nw runtime, installing multiple instances of nw on the same machine is not productive and useless.

At the moment, I am launching my apps with a shell script pointing to nw executable and passing as argument the path to my .nw archive.

The apps are located in different folders, not in the same folder as nw executable.

So far no issues, but one of the client requests is autoupdates. In order to do that I need to download a new nw archive containing the app source and replace the old one with the new one.

The problem I'm facing is not being able to find the archive path within the running app. 
Following commands fails:

- process.cwd() - pointing to unpacked archive in a temp folder.
- process.execPath - pointing to nw executable

All other attempts (ie window.location etc) fails, since all points to the unpacked files from where the app runs.

Is there a way to get the path of the original archive(nw file)?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot try it now, but `process.argv` from NodeJS API does not contain the name of archive?

Comment: No, unfortunately no. I've searched all `process` props and cannot find the name of the archive.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to install nw.js as local module: `npm install nw --save` for each your project. Then you can run your project with `npm start` command, assuming you have `"start": "./node_modules/.bin/nw"` script in the package.json.

Pros:

- you can choose nw.js version and build type (SDK/Normal) for each project
- you can update nw.js whenever you like
- you can pack the whole project into Windows/OSX/Linux installer

Cons:

- more files on disk

Bonus: If you would like to programmatically retrieve the path to the nw.js binary use:

```
var findpath = require('nw').findpath;
var nwpath = findpath();
```